# Trouble loading data for TableView from server

Tags: mysql, ios, objective-c, uitableview

Im using a web-service API to load information from a DB (mySQL). When transitioning to a UITableViewController, I retrieve an array that contains categories in the VieDidLoad method. However, I am not able to display the array of categories that I got into the table view cells. When I init the category NSMutubaleArray and hardcode it on the otherhand, the tableview does display the information. I am trying to understand what I'm doing wrong in the steps of loading this array and populating it onto the tableview. Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

//When I init the _categoryList the way below, it displays the info.
//_categoryList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Trending",@"Sports",@"Portraits", @"Art",@"IdUser", nil];
    _toCategory = [[NSString alloc]init];


//When I try to populate it from the server it doesnt work.
_categoryList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
//just call the "getCategories" command from the web API
[[API sharedInstance] commandWithParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                         @"getCategories",@"command",
                                         nil]
                           onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json) {
                               //got stream
                               NSArray *tempArray = [json objectForKey:@"result"];
                            for (int i=0;i<tempArray.count;i++){

                                [_categoryList insertObject:[tempArray objectAtIndex:i] atIndex:i];

                               }
                               //I verify that I was able to retrieve the array with the correct conent.
                               [self printArray:_categoryList];
                               NSLog(@"got categories");
                               [self.tableView reloadData];
                           }];
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE #1:**

The JSON return is an array with NSDictioanry's. I print out its contents just to make sure, by calling the JsonArray objectForKey[‘categories’] and get this:

```
   SwiphtMVPClone[2410:11303] Array at Index 0 = Trending
   SwiphtMVPClone[2410:11303] Array at Index 1 = Sports
   SwiphtMVPClone[2410:11303] Array at Index 2 = Portraits
   SwiphtMVPClone[2410:11303] Array at Index 3 = Art
```

Right now, my app is actually crashing – getting this error:

```
 [__NSCFDictionary isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x72a85d0
```

Comment: Well, your steps are right: call web service to obtain some data, when it's done a callback is called where you try to add data to _categoryList and then refresh table view. So, first, did you check what you get as response ? what is value of the dictionary named json ?

Comment: Did you check if your completion callback was being called in the main thread? You have the `reloadData` there, which needs to be in the main thread. If you fail to invoke it in the main thread it might work, it might not work, or it might even crash your app.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. i've added a little more info to the post. @yonosoytu - how do i put the reloadData in the mainthread?

Comment: You should update with the contents of `[self printArray:_categoryList];`, or search in your code where you call `isEqualToString:` and how it relates to this code. You might be reloading the table correctly, but somewhere in the table delegate you are invoking `isEqualToString:` on one of those `NSDictionary` from the JSON.

Comment: I fixed the issue! It was because I wasn't assigning the dictionary values into the array, but instead the just the dictionary itself which caused problems. Thank you very much! How do I upvote you?!